# Need help solving C++ boost compilation error

Tags: c++, boost, g++

I am trying to build a sample C++ Circular buffer code but keep running into the issue of `declaration of anonymous class must be a definition`
The sad part is that I was able to run this code earlier on my Mac but can't do so now, can you suggest can be done to find the root cause.

**Compilation**

```
g++ temp.cpp
In file included from temp.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/circular_buffer.hpp:55:
/usr/local/include/boost/circular_buffer/base.hpp:72:1: error: declaration of anonymous class must be a definition
class <int>
^
temp.cpp:9:35: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'boost::circular_buffer<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >'
      boost::circular_buffer<int> cb(3);
                                  ^
/usr/local/include/boost/circular_buffer_fwd.hpp:34:7: note: template is declared here
class circular_buffer;
      ^
2 errors generated.
```

**CODE**

```
   #include <boost/circular_buffer.hpp>
   #include <numeric>
   #include <assert.h>

    int main(int /*argc*/, char* /*argv*/[])
   {
      // create a circular buffer of capacity 3
      boost::circular_buffer<int> cb(3);

      // insert some elements into the circular buffer
      cb.push_back(1);
      cb.push_back(2);

      // assertions
      assert(cb[0] == 1);
      assert(cb[1] == 2);
      assert(!cb.full());
      assert(cb.size() == 2);
      assert(cb.capacity() == 3);

      // insert some other elements
      cb.push_back(3);
      cb.push_back(4);

      // evaluate the sum
      int sum = std::accumulate(cb.begin(), cb.end(), 0);

      // assertions
      assert(cb[0] == 2);
      assert(cb[1] == 3);
      assert(cb[2] == 4);
      assert(*cb.begin() == 2);
      assert(cb.front() == 2);
      assert(cb.back() == 4);
      assert(sum == 9);
      assert(cb.full());
      assert(cb.size() == 3);
      assert(cb.capacity() == 3);

      return 0;
   }
```

**G++ Version**

```
g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

**Boost Version is 1.63.0**

**=============== SOLVED ====================**

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this issue in my MSVC environment. Try doing a clean build of your code.

Comment: What version of gcc (`g++ --version`) are you using?

Comment: what version of boost are you using?

Comment: @Elkvis

{
g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-
gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
}

Comment: Boost version is 1.63.0

Comment: That's not g++ it's clang, please don't tag questions with [tag:g++] if you're using Apple's fake-g++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that for some reason the definition

```
template <class T, class Alloc> 
class circular_buffer                          // circular_buffer/base.hpp line 72
/*! \cond */
#if BOOST_CB_ENABLE_DEBUG
: public cb_details::debug_iterator_registry
#endif
/*! \endcond */
{ /* ... */ };
```

is corrupted. Presumably, you have some macros defined, such as

```
#define circular_buffer <int>
```

Comment: No there is not macro defined

Comment: Look at the code after preprocessing. Does your `circular_buffer/base.hpp` file look as my snippet above?

Comment: template <class T, class Alloc>
class <int>
/*! \cond */
#if BOOST_CB_ENABLE_DEBUG
: public cb_details::debug_iterator_registry
#endif
/*! \endcond */
{

  // Requirements
    //BOOST_CLASS_REQUIRE(T, boost, SGIAssignableConcept);


    //BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT((Assignable<T>));
    //BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT((CopyConstructible<T>));
    //BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT((DefaultConstructible<T>));

    // Required if the circular_buffer will be compared with anther container.
    //BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT((EqualityComparable<T>));
    //BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT((LessThanComparable<T>));

Comment: "Changing the header"? @user1918858 Don't change the header. Report a bug or fix it from the release download.